# dynamic sitemap generator in vue js project

Tags: vue.js, sitemap

i want to generate `sitemap` based on routes in vue js project but i could not find any solution for this?
i found `vue-router-sitemap` package in npm but it did not mention any example and i totally confused? what is the solution for this?
anyway is there any way to access routes object in another normal js file ?
this is the xample of that but what is the app! and how can i use these?

// sitemapMiddleware.js

```
import VueRouterSitemap      from 'vue-router-sitemap';
import path                  from 'path';
import { router }            from 'router';

export const sitemapMiddleware = () => {
  return (req, res) => {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/xml');

    const staticSitemap = path.resolve('dist/static', 'sitemap.xml');
    const filterConfig = {
      isValid: false,
      rules: [
        /\/example-page/,
        /\*/,
      ],
    };

    new VueRouterSitemap(router).filterPaths(filterConfig).build('http://example.com').save(staticSitemap);

    return res.sendFile(staticSitemap);
  };
};

app.get('/sitemap.xml', sitemapMiddleware());
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use the package you've mentioned or are you asking how to get the routes in another file?

Comment: @Dan actually both of them for finding solution

Answer (score 0):

This middleware should place in vue.config.js.